# How to add attendees to a calendar event in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, calendar

I've been searching an answer to this question for quite some time. 
I read a previous question that was asked about two years ago, but didn't find any answer ([Add participant to an event in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853610/add-participant-to-an-event-in-ios)).

So I will ask it again, as it is critical for our product and we haven't been able to find a way yet: How can you programmatically add invitees to a calendar event in iOS.

I know that the  attendees property is read-only and the ways that these EKParticipant's come into existence is omitted from the reference. 
But I also know that some apps are able to do it... so there must be a way.

Does anybody know the answer to this strange puzzle ?

Thanks a lot for your time and consideration !
Ingrid.

Comment: For me this is also an issue which is bothering me for a longer time. I was always under the impression it is not possible except when using EventKitUI, but how does an app like Calendars 5 by Readdle manage to do just that.

Comment: As per the Apple's documentation, thats not available,
https://developer.apple.com/library/content//documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004775-SW1