# Add attendees to iCloud calendar event

Tags: ios, calendar, icloud, eventkit

I am using Event Kit to read and create events. I want to be able to add attendees to such events. But as described in documentation we cannod do that with Event Kit framework:

> Event Kit provides limited access to a user’s Calendar database; it
>   does not include everything that would be desired for implementing a
>   full-featured calendar or reminder app, such as adding attendees or
>   accounts ([Link to the source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html))

I see that some apps, like *Google Calendar*, can do that. I think that they are using *CalDAV* protocol, but I could not find anything about that (documentation, tutorials, other helpfull resources) and I don't know where to start.

Any help would be welcome.
Thanks

UPDATE:
Possible duplicate of:
[Add participant to an event in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10853610/add-participant-to-an-event-in-ios)

Anyway, I will try to post here my research updates.

Comment: I'm a little confused why you have issues with that: "CalDAV protocol, but I could not find anything about that". Eg just entering caldav.com or caldav.org gives you plenty of information, let alone Google. What did you try and what are you missing. This is a good resource http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/. Or this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LzgomnabxdM ;-)

Comment: @hnh thanks for your comment. The resources looks helpful. But still I would love to find something specific for iOS. And for now I could not find any libraries/tools to work with CalDAV.

Comment: The CalConnect list of implementations is well maintained and pretty complete. If none of them pleases you, you likely need to roll your own.